# How to redirects all pages of my website to login.aspx ? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing project on `localhost` and I want when user open any page except `home.aspx`,`contact.aspx`,`about.aspx`,`services.aspx` then it redirects to `login.aspx` if user is not logged in.

And second thing is I'm facing issue `object reference not set of instance object` in code below.

I want that when user's session expire then it also redirects to `login.aspx`.
I'm trying to secure my project pages.Thanks and sorry for bad English.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   welcome.InnerText = Session["name"].ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: include the code that throws the exception

Comment: For the session part of your question, couldn't you just check if the session value is set to null (at a time when you know it should hold value), and if it is null to do your redirect?

Comment: Try out what I suggested, else post here so I can help.

Comment: @Hameed, You need to add some code to your question where you are getting an error of  `object reference not set of instance object`, else this question will be on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following in your web config in `system.web` section.

```
 <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
 </authorization>
```

The above will not allow access to any page in website by unauthenticated users. Now add a section for each page that you want unauthenticated users to access by using the following configuration in web config file. Add the config below just before the closing `configuration` tag.
*I am assuming all allowed pages are under your website's root.*

```
  <location path="Home.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

**Sample Web Config using above sections**

```
<configuration> 
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms" />
  <!--this is the first part-->
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
  <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="540"/>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
</system.web>
  <!--this is the second part-->
  <location path="Home.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Services.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Contact.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="About.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

NOTE: If the pages you want to allow access to unauthenticated users is not under website root but under some folder like `customer/Services.aspx` then make sure to replace the path with `customer/Services.aspx` in above configuration. This is shown as below.

**Config when allowed page is NOT under website root but under some folder**

```
  <location path="customer/Services.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Regarding your second issue, you should check whether the session variable of `name` exists when getting it's value. So, you need to use code as below.

**Second Issue Resolution**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  if (Session["name"] != null) 
   { 
     welcome.InnerText = Session["name"].ToString(); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: what is this i don't understand?Can you help me

Comment: You should first open the web config file in your ASP.Net project and then insert the code that I have provided at appropriate places.

Comment: here is my `web.config` file `<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="540"/>
    
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>`

Comment: Where i should put your code in `web.config` file?

Comment: Add the second part for each page just before `</configuration>`. So you will have to add the section for Home.aspx, Contact.aspx, Services.aspx and About.aspx. This means 4 such sectios for second code snippet. Once you get this part then I will tell you where to put the first part that I mentioned.

Comment: I have added this code in `web.config` file under `system.web` `<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
 </authorization>` now i don't know how to put other code in all pages?I want to put this code in `aspx` or `aspx.cs` and please tell me at which place.thanks

Comment: So you have done the first part. Can you do the second part as I have mentioned in last comment.

Comment: you have `teamviwer` or `anydisk` software?can you help me on my laptop please

Comment: Let me paste the web config for you according to what you mentioned in the comment. Give me 2 minutes.

Comment: how to do second part?

Comment: Look at the `Sample web cofig` that I just added to my answer using the web config you have. That should make it easy for you to add the suggested configuration in web config file.

Comment: Ok let me check, i paste this code in `web.config` and then i tell you and then you tell me what i do next

Comment: Make sure that the pages Home.aspx, Services.aspx, Contact.aspx and About.aspx are in the root of your ASP.Net website.

Comment: Now I have done.I past this code in `web.config` file now what i want to do next?

Comment: Let's go to discussion. You need to save the web config file and run your ASP.Net website from Visual Studio.

Comment: Sunil what do you mean?I don't understand sorry.How can i put  these pages in root?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117222/discussion-between-hameed-and-sunil).

Answer (score 1):

What @Sunil contributed will deny unknown users. That way if the session has expired, the user will be denied access. The issue is that this will block access to the whole site, and @Hameed is asking for specific pages to still be accessible. The way that I typically structure the site is to put the un-secure pages in the root, and put the secure pages in a subdirectory. Then create a new web.config file for the security.